# put javascript array on jsp and to loop via form:select

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsp, spring-form

I want to loop an array on JSP with that select tag

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>

<form:select path="attributeId" id="attributeId">
   <form:options items="${attrib}" id="attrib" />
</form:select>
<div id="jsonVal"></div>
```

script.js function:

```
function parseJson(string){
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
list = [];
for(var i = 0; i < obj.ArrayList.length; i++){
    list[i] = obj.ArrayList[i].id + " "
    + obj.ArrayList[i].game.id + " "
    + obj.ArrayList[i].game.name + " "
    + obj.ArrayList[i].gameId + " "
    + obj.ArrayList[i].name;
}
document.getElementById("attrib").innerHTML = list;
document.getElementById("jsonVal").innerHTML = list;
}
```

I can see the output on div but the problem is I can't assign and iterate JS array var on jsp.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I want to put the array from js into form:select tag on jsp